# Is it possible to run the same app+db on each node with kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run web app and db on each node using kubernetes, the db on each node needs to be synchronised with the other dbs. I need the app and db on each node in case of node failure and 3 replicas on the same node.
If it's not possible, what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the DB part and it will be easy. Include the DB part and it will range from headache to impossible. What is a db (SQL/NoSQL/in-memory)? Each one needs to be handled differently and I don't want to start about horizontal scaling of SQL databases... You will either need a better design or you will need to delegate the database handling to some cloud provider or you will need to find someone pretty skilled to make it work (production ready).

Answer (score 1):

> I need the app and db on each node in case of node failure and 3 replicas on the same node.

This is rare - since if all replicas are on the *same* Node - that does not tolerate "node failure" since all three will be down.

The common use is to use a *distributed database* - e.g. with built-in replication. For example [CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/product/). And configure it with at least 3 instances - but spread to *different* Nodes - or preferably in a **regional** cluster spread over 3 Availability Zones - so that it tolerate failure of a whole data center.

> I want to run web app and db on each node using kubernetes

A web app is accessing the DB over a network connection - so they don't necessarily need to be located on the same Node. But you may be interested in e.g. [Redis](https://redis.io/) for this e.g. for fast cache of data.

Instead, it is important that both e.g. the web app and the db is spread to different failure domains. For example different Availability Zones or for a *zonal* cluster, different Nodes.